# For $H\lhd G,$ is it true that $O_{\pi}(H)\le O_{\pi}(G)$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\pi$ be a set of primes, and a $\pi$-group is defined as a finite group with each prime divisor of the order of the group is contained in $\pi$.

Let $O_{\pi}(G)$ denotes the unique largest normal $\pi$ subgroup of finite group $G$ and $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G.$
Can we prove that $$O_{\pi}(H)\le O_{\pi}(G)\,\,\ ?$$

Comment: Well some of us can prove it!

Comment: Perhaps of interest: what you call $O_\pi$ is sometimes called the normal core.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: since $O_{\pi}(.)$ is a *characteristic* subgroup in which it is defined, we have $O_{\pi}(H)\text{ char } H \unlhd G$, so $O_{\pi}(H) \unlhd G$ and it is a $\pi$-subgroup. So $O_{\pi}(H) \subseteq O_{\pi}(G)$.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a hint so much as a complete answer!